# Дублируются записи в бд

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть форма добавления данных в бд

```
</head>
<body>
<center>
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="lrsqkuxp_bd";
$pass="RISEZID123"; //установленный вами пароль
$db_name="lrsqkuxp_bd";
$link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

//Если переменная Name передана
if (isset($_POST["Quiz"])) {
    //Вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `products` (`Quiz`, `Answer`) 
                        VALUES ('".$_POST['Quiz']."','".$_POST['Answer']."')");
    //Если вставка прошла успешно
    if ($sql) {
        echo "<p>Данные успешно добавлены! Спасибо, Вам, за участие.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
    }
} 
?>

<table>
<form action="" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td>Ваш вопрос:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Quiz"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ответ на вопрос:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Answer"  ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"  style="margin-left: 100px;" value="Добавить запись"></td>
    </tr>
</form>
</table>

</body>
```

В базу данных они вносят корректно, но потом если пару раз перезагрузить страницу, то последняя записать почему-то дублируется от 1 до N раз
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну так при обновлении страницы код еще раз выполняется. принимайте меры что бы не сажать дубли. например проверяйте что в базе еще нет записей с точно такими же данными как собираетесь записать

Comment: Боритесь с дубляжом бескомпромиссным методом установки ограничений в базе данных. Вам дан такой могучий инструмент, а вы как в каменном веке живёте. Ну чего стоит построить уникальный индекс? `create unique index products_unique_idx on products (Quiz, Answer)` Всё. Дублей не будет как ни старайся.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, что перезагружая страницу вы заново отправляете данные на сервер, в следствие чего они записываются в базу еще ровно столько раз, сколько вы страницу перезагружали.

Можно бороться следующими путями:

1) вам предложили в комментарии добавить полю свойство уникальности "unique", т.е. второй раз в этом столбце это значение точно не появится;

2) проверять перед добавлением, есть ли в базе уже такая же запись, и если есть, то не записывать;

3) хранить где-то информацию о том, что значения с этой формы вы уже получали (в сессии или куках, например)...

Если у вас это какой-то тест, куда записываются какие-то вопросы/ответы и это поле по умолчанию не может быть уникальным, то самое простое сделать как-нибудь из 3го варианта:

1) при показе формы создать `$_SESSION['form_add'] = true;` , а при добавлении (получении данных) проверить, есть ли этот $_SESSION['form_add'], и если нет, то добавить данные и сделать `unset($_SESSION['form_add']);`...

2) хранить это в куках...

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<?php
$host="localhost";
$user="lrsqkuxp_bd";
$pass="RISEZID123"; //установленный вами пароль
$db_name="lrsqkuxp_bd";
$link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

//Если переменная Name передана
if (isset($_POST['form_add']) && isset($_SESSION['form_add']) && ($_POST['form_add']==$_SESSION['form_add'])) {
    //Вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `products` (`Quiz`, `Answer`) 
                        VALUES ('".$_POST['Quiz']."','".$_POST['Answer']."')");
    //Если вставка прошла успешно
    if ($sql) {
        echo "<p>Данные успешно добавлены! Спасибо, Вам, за участие.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Произошла ошибка.</p>";
    }
unset($_SESSION['form_add']);
} 
?>

<?php
$_SESSION['form_add'] = md5(time().'+'.rand(0,1000));
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="form_add" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['form_add'];?>">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Ваш вопрос:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Quiz"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ответ на вопрос:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Answer"  ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"  style="margin-left: 100px;" value="Добавить запись"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Конечно, решение может быть и более изящным =)

Comment: В куках и сессии это может вызвать ошибки. Простой способ редирект после отправки на success page формы.

Comment: @Naumov , да верно! про редирект я забыл )))